# Wicket Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given

Tags: spring, constructor, wicket, superclass

I get this error trying to instantiate this class:

```
public class ActivationAjaxBehavior extends AbstractAjaxBehavior {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3103844752146887631L;

private final String tokenKey = "token";

@SpringBean
private RegistrationService registrationService;

public ActivationAjaxBehavior() {
    super();
    //Injector.get().inject(this);
}

@Override
public void onRequest() {
    RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
    ServletWebRequest webRequest = (ServletWebRequest) requestCycle
            .getRequest();
    HttpServletRequest request = webRequest.getContainerRequest();
    String extractedToken = (String) request.getParameter(tokenKey);    
    try {
        registrationService.confirmUser(extractedToken);
        proceedToSignInPage();
    } catch (WrongTokenException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        proceedToSignUpPage();
    }   
}

private void proceedToSignInPage() {
    throw new RestartResponseException(
            SignInPage.class); 
}

private void proceedToSignUpPage() {
    throw new RestartResponseException(
            RegisterPage.class); 
}
```

}

I think that @SpringBean is the issue here. But it is available in the spring container... it's perfectly available elsewhere...

```
@Bean
public IRegistrationService userRegistrationService() {
    return new RegistrationService(databaseBean());
}
```

with that injector unhashed it get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error while injecting object
Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is pretty clear. In order to inject dependency using `@SpringBean` your class which is being injected has to meet these requirements:

1. To have a constructor which has no arguments
2. If this class extends some other class, then this superclass must have a constructor which has no arguments.
3. Implement an interface to proxy the class.

Your problem is either of the first or second rule. So check these conditions and fix your problem according to them.

Comment: But it does have a default constructor, does it not? :). I wouldn't be able to write a constructor of the child class with no constructor of parent one called... and it is always called - default by default... yep?

Comment: I don't know if `RegistrationService` has a default constructor :) Most likely it doesn't, I am assuming from this line: `return new RegistrationService(databaseBean());` You are trying to inject this instance: `RegistrationService`, so it must meet the requirements.

Comment: Hm but it already is in the spring IoC container - why it's trying to instantiate it again?

Comment: Wicket is generating a Proxy for your bean - which is generated with CGLib and as this needs a default constructor.